# Deleting object in Django

Tags: django

What is the best practice to delete object in Django? Using simple "a tag" with the link to the view like this:

```
def deleteStudent(request,id):
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id = id)
    student.delete()
    return redirect('/')
```

or using post method:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    Are you want to delete this item ?
    <input type="submit" value="Yes" />
    <a href="/">Cancel </a>
</form>
```

and in views:

```
def deleteStudent(request, id):
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, id = id)

    if request.method =="POST":
        student.delete()
        return redirect('/')
 
    return render(request, "delete_view.html")
```

I saw in courses that people use both of the methods (it's example code, I'didn't test it or secure views). So if we can delete objects with "POST" method, can I say in the job interview that "POST method can be also used to delete objects"? Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former violates the HTTP standard. As the standard on [*safe methods* of the HTTP specifications [w3.org]](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1) says:

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods **SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval**. These methods ought to be considered "safe".

You thus can not let a GET request remove an item: scrapers like a Google bot might accidentally trigger this view, and thus remove data.

If you want to remove items, usually you do this by a DELETE request, or a POST request. This is also how the [**`DeleteView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) is implemented: it will remove the object for a DELETE or POST request. The idea is that for a GET request, you can render a template for example that asks if you are sure you want to remove that item, and thus then make a POST (or DELETE) request when the user confirms.

Often the view will also check if the user is authorized to do so: for example if only the "owner" of an object is allowed to remove such item, then the view should validate this.

> I saw in courses that people use both of the methods.

The first one is *not* a good idea, and *violates* the HTTP standards. Any course that uses this introduces security risks.